# Am I going crazy? jQuery .click() doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, click

Code below doesn't work on any browser. It's supposed to show an alert box. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#prevlink').click(function () { 
  alert("Test"); 
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="prevlink" href="#">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will make a good tech interview question - "What does this code do?"

Comment: @Mike: When I read the first half of your comment I couldn't help laughing. "Am I crazy?" :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not wrapping the function in a [`ready()` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). It runs before the DOM exists.

Answer (score 5):

Put it in document.ready!

Comment: +1 Although the question technically is if the OP is crazy. :P

Comment: oh, and you may want to return false from the click() handler if you don't want the page to navigate back to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the element before it exists (JavaScript is run inline with HTML parsing/rendering). You can either use the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event that jQuery provides as Pekka and Mike pointed out, or just make sure you're trying to access the element *after* it exists:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="prevlink" href="#">test</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
// By this time we get here, it exists.
$('#prevlink').click(function () { 
    alert("Test"); 
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The former (using a `ready` event or similar) is more "unobtrusive" and that's very useful when you're dealing with large teams, where your HTML designers and JavaScript coders are usually different people. The latter happens sooner (no small gap in time after the link appears and before you hook the click event), and so is [what the Google Closure team recommend](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41/1f5f44b00d5649b5) for hooking up element handlers.

Even when using the second method, you can keep your JavaScript and HTML *reasonably* separated, by ensuring that the `script` tag is just a call to set up the element and has no actual logic of its own.

Comment: This is the best answer.  I had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964609/why-doesnt-my-external-jquery-click-event-work-in-jade/19964811#19964811 and although the other answers above fixed it for me, I didn't exactly understand why until u explained it.  If u submit a link or any answer on my page, I'll give u my green checkmark.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$(function()
{
  $('#prevlink').click(function () { 
    alert("Test"); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the javascript code executed before the html finished downloading
Use this instead as your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#prevlink').click(function(){
  alert("Test");
});
})
```